# How do I recursively get all directories that contain a txt file with the same name as the containing directory in Bash?

Tags: bash, files, directory

Let's say I have the following:

```
./
   Dir1/
      Sub1/
           Sub1.jpg
      Sub2/
           Sub2.jpg
           Sub2.png
           Sub2.txt
   Dir2/
      Sub1/
           Sub1.doc
           Sub1.txt
      Sub2/
           Sub2.jpg
           Sub2.png
           SomeTxt.txt
   Dir3/
      Dir3.txt
   Dir4/
      Sub1/
           Dir4.txt
      Some.txt
```

Using bash (bashrc in my case), how can I get a variable that contains all of the directories containing a text file (.txt) with the same name as the containing directory? So from the example above I would want to have a variable containing the following:

```
./Dir1/Sub2/    
./Dir1/Sub1/
./Dir3/
```

It shouldn't return `./Dir1/Sub1/` because it doesn't have a `Sub1.txt` file.

It shoudn't return `./Dir2/Sub2/` because the txt file in it isn't `Sub2.txt`.

It shouldn't return `./Dir4/` or `./Dir4/Sub1/` because `Dir4.txt` is not directly in `./Dir4/`.

**NOTE**:

The names of the directories don't have to be these names in particular.  What is important is that the txt file's name matches the containing directory's name.

Also, I know other languages might be easier but I need it in bash.

Comment: In Python: `dirs = (path.parent for path in Path().rglob('*.txt') if path.parent.name == path.stem)`

Comment: It should be noted that `dir3.txt` and `dir3` are **not** the same name.

Comment: @andrea the name of the directory should match the name of the file without the extension. So because Dir3.txt is in the Dir3 directory, It would return ./Dir3/

Comment: @andrea I added the forward slash you each directory to help show that they are not files.

Comment: What does this have to do with the bashrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
$ tree somepath/
somepath/
├── Dir1
│   ├── Sub1
│   │   └── Sub1.jpg
│   └── Sub2
│       ├── Sub2.jpg
│       ├── Sub2.png
│       └── Sub2.txt
├── Dir2
│   ├── Sub1
│   │   ├── Sub1.doc
│   │   └── Sub1.txt
│   └── Sub2
│       ├── SomeTxt.txt
│       ├── Sub2.jpg
│       └── Sub2.png
├── Dir3
│   └── Dir3.txt
└── Dir4
    ├── Some.txt
    └── Sub1
        └── Dir4.txt

9 directories, 12 files
```

then, with the shell's globstar option enabled (`shopt -s globstar`)

```
for d in somepath/**/; do
    d="${d%/}"
    [[ -f "${d}/${d##*/}.txt" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$d"
done
somepath/Dir1/Sub2
somepath/Dir2/Sub1
somepath/Dir3
```

---

If you want to store the results in an array for later processing, you can do that using the shell's built-in `mapfile` (or its synonym `readarray`) e.g.

```
mapfile -t TXT_DIRS < <(
  for d in somepath/**/; do
    d="${d%/}"
    [[ -f "${d}/${d##*/}.txt" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$d"
  done
)
```

**NOTE:** *it would be better practice to null-terminate the list using one of the methods discussed in* [bash: whitespace-safe procedural use of find into select](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378304/65304)

You can then iterate over the array like so

```
for d in "${TXT_DIRS[@]}"; do
    echo "$d"
done
somepath/Dir1/Sub2
somepath/Dir2/Sub1
somepath/Dir3
```

Alternatively, you could avoid storing the results at all and simply process each directory as you find it i.e.

```
for d in somepath/**/; do 
    d="${d%/}"
    [[ -f "${d}/${d##*/}.txt" ]] && echo "Doing something with $d"
done
Doing something with somepath/Dir1/Sub2
Doing something with somepath/Dir2/Sub1
Doing something with somepath/Dir3
```

Comment: So would I make it `TXT_DIR=for d in somepath/**/; do d="${d%/}"; [[ -f "${d}/${d##*/}.txt" ]]; done` to get the variable?

Comment: You would need the *command substitution* syntax, `$(...)` i.e. `TXT_DIR=$(for d in somepath/**/; do d="${d%/}"; [[ -f "${d}/${d##*/}.txt" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$d"; done)`. What do you intend to do with it though? Multiline text isn't often very useful - an array may be a better option.

Comment: How would you make that as array? Eventually I want to perform an operation on the file that also needs the folder. The operation will be like this `operation original/Dir1/Sub2/Sub2.txt newpath/Dir1/Sub2/Output/`

Comment: @kingcobra1986: in Python: `for path in dirs: operation(path, Path('newpath') / path.relative_to(Path('original')).parent / 'Output')` where [`dirs` is defined above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960054/how-do-i-recursively-get-all-directories-that-contain-a-txt-file-with-the-same-n#comment1533964_960054)

Comment: @kingcobra1986 please see updated answer

Comment: @steeldriver the last part with the for loop was how I ultimately did it.

Answer (score 0):

This is practically the same as steeldriver's answer, but it loops over each txt file instead of over each dir. Hopefully it's easier to understand too.

Since you mentioned in a comment that you don't actually need an array, I've left out that step.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.txt; do
    d="$(dirname "$f")"
    if [[ $(basename "$f") == $(basename "$d").txt ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$d"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
./Dir1/Sub2
./Dir2/Sub1
./Dir3
```